# Struggling with Transition from Software Engineering to Control Engineering in Master's Program

Tags: masters, electrical-engineering

I'm currently a master's student in control engineering, with a background in software engineering. The transition has been quite challenging for me, as the control courses are proving to be extremely math-intensive, and my lack of prior knowledge in this field is making it even more difficult. While I am passionate about control engineering and have a clear vision for my research area, I am finding it hard to keep up with the coursework.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or tips on how to manage this transition effectively and improve my understanding of the fundamental concepts in control engineering. Additionally, any guidance on coping with the rigorous coursework would be invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

You would not be the first student to run into this issue, and your title strongly suggests where it's coming from.

Electrical engineering is broadly split into two halves. One half is applied physics: semiconductors, nanotechnology, circuits, electromagnetics. The other half is mathematics: control theory, digital signal processing, communication algorithms. Many departments are split along these lines, and in fact the bolded title of my Master's diploma specifies which half.

PhD-level control engineering is 2/3 mathematical theory, e.g. manipulating equations and writing proofs. The applied 1/3 is motivating the problem and testing your solution works.

The problem I see is two-fold. One, you didn't come into control from an undergrad degree in EE or ME, which would expose you to mathematics background. Second, and I don't regularly do CS, but software engineering seems to be firmly on the applied side of CS. If you said theoretical computer science or cryptography, that would be a different scenario.

As mathematicians can tell you, developing good theoretical skills, writing proofs, takes many years of work, even starting in high school. It's something that simply requires experience. You probably have a little over a year to figure it out.

My advice is 1: look at how well you did in theoretical CS classes. The classes where you had to use equations and not write software. Did you do well and enjoy it? If so the problem may be more towards specifics than general skills. This is something you can reasonably fix with study and tutoring.

2: If you weren't interested in math, then get out of control. Your previous experience in software engineering suggests this. If you're just in for a masters, slog through, try to take more applied classes (vehicle control vs nonlinear control), and that's that. If you were planning on continuing onto a PhD, you need to switch fields ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

You are tackling a new field. The biggest issue is you do not kwow what you do not know (no, the "maths" is too general, it is not a good description).

Sometimes, when we are presented a new topic or a new field, we struggle to adapt our mindset to the different mindset needed to approach it.

Part of it is the novelty of the topic and the way it is presented, but part of it is brain "resistance" (neurocognitive experts feel free to tackle in): we adapted and we were succesful doing thing one way, why should the brain do the effort to learn new things?

However, the human brain is good at making connections.

What can be helpful is to slightly throw off-guard the brain, by studying the same topic you are struggling with on a different text-book than the one used during the course (your library or your librarian or one of the many online courses will help you in finding one).

Your brain will try hard to make the connection between the lecture content and the "new" book content. In a couple of weeks of deep,full-time dive in the topic, you will be familiar with the topic, and you will be able to exactly describe what you know you know and especially what you know you **don't** know.

At that point, it is up to you if you will find out you are fine with "patching the gaps" in your maths knowledge, or if you need to attend the Maths exams of the control engineering Bachelor course.